# TypeScript IDE that show all the compilation errors in the project (not just open files)

Tags: typescript, ide

I tried:
- Eclipse ( Codemix plugin, Palantir TS plugin, Wild Web Developer plugin)
- VisualStudio Code

All of them seem to only show errors on open files.
Is there an IDE out there that would show the compilation errors of all files in the project?

Bonus: Is there a reason why this is not a standard feature for TS compared to other languages like Java IDEs for example?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says pretty clearly that questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All of them seem to only show errors on open files. Is there an IDE out there that would show the compilation errors of all files in the project

VSCode does that if you configure a watch task.

## Configure a watch task

Add to your `package.json` `scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc --watch --noEmit --project './tsconfig.json'"
  },
```

Configure `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "watch",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "revealProblems": "onProblem"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now from vscode command pallete > `Tasks: Run Task` > `npm: watch`

## More

Steps covered here : https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_modifying-an-existing-problem-matcher

## Personal thoughts

I've worked on other things that have done full typescript watching in IDEs e.g. `atom-typescript` (when it used my project service implementation) `alm-tools` (http://alm-tools.github.io/) an IDE I designed for TypeScript when the world was shifting from atom to vscode, and now planning a product aimed at UI designers that does full project watching : https://designtsx.com/